# Textfield ignores the Binding's getter value in iOS 17

Tags: swift, swiftui, binding

In the below example, no matter how `userPhoneNumber` gets modified, the `Textfield's` value displayed stays as if the getter value of the binding is ignored.

```
@Binding var userPhoneNumber: String

var body: some View {
     TextField("", text: Binding(get: {
            userPhoneNumber
        }, set: { value in
            let containsOnlyDigits = value.allSatisfy("0123456789".contains)
            
            guard containsOnlyDigits else {
                return
            }
            
            userPhoneNumber = value
        }))
}
```

I've put logs and confirmed that the getter is called every time and that the `userPhoneNumber` has the correct value.

Taking this into account it is fair to assume that passing a constant binding would still allow the `Textfield` to be modified by the user.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Binding<String> = .constant("1")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: value)
        }
    }
}
```

Running this example confirms the Textfield's input is modified by the user even if the passed binding is constant if the simulator is iOS 17+. Testing it on a device with iOS 17+ replicates the same behaviour as the simulator.

This however was not the case with the iOS 16 simulator and I bet would not be the case on a device running iOS 16 as well.

How to force the `TextField` to respect the binding's getter in iOS 17?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a different approach using `.onChange`,
to display only numbers in your TextField.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value = "1"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55) {
            Text(value) // <-- for testing
            TestingView(userPhoneNumber: $value)
        }
    }
}

struct TestingView: View {
    @Binding var userPhoneNumber: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $userPhoneNumber)
            .border(.red)
            .onChange(of: userPhoneNumber) { old, new in
                if new.allSatisfy("0123456789".contains) {
                    userPhoneNumber = new
                } else {
                    userPhoneNumber = old
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, good answer. I've considered that, but still wondering if maybe there's an uknown change in the API which I don't know about which anyone can point out regarding the Binding. I suppose it's linked with their addition of new storage management (Bindable, etc) somehow.

Comment: This have got to be a bug. Experiencing the same, even on iOS 16 it doesn't seem to be "consistent" (e.g. limiting TF value to 6 chars, sometimes the 7th appears and then it dissapears). Toggle on other hand seems to work just fine on both iOS 16 and 17. The approach with onChange works flawlessly but it requires the model to expose its properties for 2-way binding to take place which then remains exposed wherever the model is used at.